# Insert statement fails in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['tag_h1']) && isset($_POST['tag_h2']) && isset($_POST['tag_metadata']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['postContent']))
{    
    $tag_h1=$_POST['tag_h1'];
    $tag_h2=$_POST['tag_h2'];
    $tag_metadata=$_POST['tag_metadata'];       
    $content=$_POST['postContent'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $isTop=isset($_POST['isTop'])?1:0;
    $query = "INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top) VALUES ('".$tag_h1."', '".$tag_h2."', '".$tag_metadata."', '".$content."', '".$title."'".$isTop."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The above statement fails. An exception is thrown. I cant see any, cause Chrome freezes.. other browsers go blank.. and I can't see any error!

Does anyone know why my insert statement is wrong?

Comment: Please pleeeease [escape your strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com/) alert!

Comment: i dont care about security for this site..stop commenting about it all the time

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd great attitude

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Even if you don't care about security (which is a silly approach anyway), it may cause problems like you are having here. If one of your strings contains an innocent `'` it will break your SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing: "," and a missing "'"

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top) VALUES ('".$tag_h1."', '".$tag_h2."', '".$tag_metadata."', '".$content."', '".$title."'".$isTop."')";
```

Between `'".$title."'".$isTop."'`

Should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top) VALUES ('".$tag_h1."', '".$tag_h2."', '".$tag_metadata."', '".$content."', '".$title."', '".$isTop."')";
```

Comment: it depends on your error_reporting level on php settings. but you can always check apache error_log what op system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You have specified 6 columns to insert and only 5 values :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top) 
VALUES (
     '".$tag_h1."', '"
     .$tag_h2."', '"
     .$tag_metadata."', '"
     .$content."', '"
     .$title."'".$isTop."')";
```

Perhaps you missed a comma ?

### And [please make sure you have a read about SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top) VALUES ('".$tag_h1."', '".$tag_h2."', '".$tag_metadata."', '".$content."', '".$title."'".$isTop."')";
```

To this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic
            (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top)
          VALUES
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($tag_h1)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($tag_h2)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($tag_metadata)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($isTop)."')";
```

You forgot a `, '`, and you didn't escape your input.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the freezing, but:

```
'".$title."'".$isTop."'
```

should be

```
'".$title."', '".$isTop."'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//checking that they're all set won't do anything, because, unless it's a checkbox,
//it's always set if it's in the form
//So you should check if the submit button has been set (form submitted)
//And that the inputs are !empty()
//Also, for future reference, isset() can take multiple arguments and will return true if all arguments are set or false if one isn't.  empty() only takes one argument though.
if( (isset($_POST['submitbutton']) || isset($_POST['submitbutton_x'])) //checking for the submitname_x is a fix for image submit buttons on IE
    && !empty($_POST['title']) 
    && !empty($_POST['tag_h1']) 
    && !empty($_POST['tag_h2']) 
    && !empty($_POST['tag_metadata']) 
    && !empty($_POST['title']) 
    && !empty($_POST['postContent']) )
{ 

    $tag_h1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag_h1']);  //Always escape directly used input!
    $tag_h2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag_h2']);
    $tag_metadata = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag_metadata']);       
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postContent']);
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);

    $isTop = isset($_POST['isTop'])?1:0;


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top)';
    $query = sprintf("%s VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d)",$sql,$tag_h1,$tag_h2,$tag_metadata,$content,$title,$isTop);
    //I assume is_top is an int or tinyint or whatever field 
    //and as such should not have single quotes around it.

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing: comma and single quote between last tow values.:

Your query should be changed to :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic (tag_h1,tag_h2,tag_metadata,content,title,is_top) VALUES ('".$tag_h1."', '".$tag_h2."', '".$tag_metadata."', '".$content."', '".$title."', '".$isTop."')";
```